# Functions in JavaScript are not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

I created a function that could be called once the user focus on the input field;  when I tried to apply and test it myself though,  no function had been called.  I checked for my function,  it was well-written;  I found no syntax mistakes.  I created some tricks to find out what kind of a problem I had had: The outcome is that the same code could be applied with the event "onfocus", whereas the browser totally ignored my function even when I created the inline code within the tag "input"...Taking into notice I am using Firefox,  and the test was on Firefox 52.0.2 (32-bit) on Ubuntu Linux..

The testing function code: 
(In script element):

```
function helpMe(){
  alert("Help Me!");
};
```

(Within the input tag):

```
onfous="help me()" // NOT WORKING!
```

(Within the input tag):

```
onfocus="alert('Help Me!')" // WORKING WELL!
```

Comment: Format code by indenting it by four spaces, or highlighting it and pressing ctrl+k. It's quite unreadable as is.

Comment: And when you call the function, you have an erroneous space in the name. That should have reported an error in your console.

Comment: Is it really "onfous"? That won't work either.

Comment: This is a trivial error... you should take more time to debug and check over your code before rushing to Stack Overflow for assistance. The community here can be pretty hard on simple mistakes like this.

Answer (score -1):

you have a typo

```
<script> 
   function helpMe(){ alert("Help Me!"); }
</script>
```

(Within the input tag):

```
// here helpMe instead of help me .. 
<input onfous="helpMe()"/>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this almost definitely would have caused an error in the console. Always check the console when things aren't working right.

Comment: Is your second code fragment supposed to fix the error? It seems unlikely that `onfous` will work properly.